# React & Material-UI – Custom theme within custom component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I have React app (functional components) and I use Material-UI. I have custom theme also and I use theme provider. I have created custom component (e.g. MySuperContainer) and I need to connect it with particular styles (object) in my theme

```
export const myTheme = { …, components: { MySuperContainer: { padding: “10px“, … }  … }
```

I don’t want to import it to component to `sx` via `useTheme` hook. I don’t want to use styled components nor anything similar. Finally I want to write `<MySuperContainer />` and it should already find its own custom styles in `myTheme`.

How can I achieve this? Is there any example or tutorial how to do this? I cannot find anything.